# button with a comment

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

Is it possible to enter a comment for a button, if you move the mouse over it it will be displayed. Just like with a cell in Excel. I don't want to use Excel VBA, because I have create a template, which changes everytime. Unless it works automatically, the template can be provided with a comment

that the button have a comment

Comment: It depends. **1.** What kind of button is it? **2.** What does it do?